# JSON remove spaces and carriage returns, but preserve spaces in quotes

Tags: json, spaces, reformat

I need to take a JSON object like this:

```
{
  "name": "This is a name",
  "description": "This is    the description"
}
```

and remove the all carriage returns and the spaces NOT in quotes. So the result should look like this:

```
{"name":"This is a name","description":"This is    the description"}
```

The spaces inside quotes need to be preserved.

A jQuery solution is fine.

Thanks!

-Matt

Comment: How do you have the object stored? Unless it's as a string or read from somewhere as a string, there's no reason it would contain line returns or extraneous spaces. Can you give a little more detail?

Comment: I was inexact in my language. It is NOT an object, but getting it as a string. I am getting the JSON as text from a textarea in a form. The user is entering the data, most likely by copy and paste.

Comment: Both versions represent the same JSON - the first is just "pretty printed". Any parser should be able to parse any of that valid JSON into a corresponding representation. So, actually, you _don't need_ it ;)  There may be JSON generators which take a representation and output "pretty" JSON or terse JSON through specifying an option parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're getting it from a text field as a string, you should be able to just use builtins for modern JavaScript:

```
var asObj = JSON.parse(asStr);
// now you have an object for use.
// assuming you want it back as a str
var asStr2 = JSON.stringify(asObj);
```

That should do most the stripping for you.

Comment: This did not work as described, the newlines still exist in the final asStr2

Comment: @LessQuesar - I am not sure you are looking for the same question as the OP - in their comment below the question they clarify that the input data is as a string (from a user's input). `JSON.parse(inputData)` will give the object representation (which has no concept of the spacing outside the quotes). `JSON.stringify(obj)` would turn it into the second code block they show (which is truncated in StackOverflow comments...).

Comment: my bad it was a similar but different issue then the one solved with your code. I agree your solution works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue withe carriage return when reading the CSV file and put it in to the JSON:

```
var json = JSON.stringify({"name": "This is a name","description": "This is    the description"});
json = json.replace(/\\r/g, '');
```

You have to use the `\\r` instead of `\r` because of escaped carriage return.